# Миграция кода из python2 в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Имеется код на Python 2 для отправки пуш-уведомлений через Firebase

```
import sys
from urllib2 import *
import json
import urllib

MY_API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE"

messageTitle = sys.argv[1]
messageBody = sys.argv[2]

data={
    "to" : "/topics/my_little_topic",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : messageBody,
        "title" : messageTitle,
        "icon" : "ic_cloud_white_48dp"
    }
}

dataAsJSON = json.dumps(data)

request = Request(
    "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
    dataAsJSON,
    { "Authorization" : "key="+MY_API_KEY,
      "Content-type" : "application/json"
    }
)

print urlopen(request).read()
```

С помощью утилиты 2to3 код был "интерпретирован" в Python3

```
import sys
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

MY_API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE"

messageTitle = sys.argv[1]
messageBody = sys.argv[2]

data={
    "to" : "/topics/my_little_topic",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : messageBody,
        "title" : messageTitle,
        "icon" : "ic_cloud_white_48dp"
    }
}

dataAsJSON = json.dumps(data)

request = Request(
    "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
    dataAsJSON,
    { "Authorization" : "key="+MY_API_KEY,
      "Content-type" : "application/json"
    }
)

print(urlopen(request).read())
```

Проблема в том, что при исполнении выдает такую ошибку

```
 request = Request(
NameError: name 'Request' is not defined
```

Хотя все либы подключены и установлены
С Python2 проблем нет
На питоне не пишу, нужен единоразово для решения конкретной задачи, поэтому особенностей языка не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
```

Comment: Изначальная ошибка исчезла, но появилась новая  TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.    в строке print(urlopen(request).read())

Comment: `dataAsJSON.encode(),`